# Deploy only one endpoint of a service containing multiple endpoints

Tags: spring-boot, rest, service, deployment, endpoint

I have one springboot service which contains multiple endpoints(say 8). Now I want to reuse that service and deploy on some new environment, but I only need one endpoint of that service. Is it possible to deploy just a single endpoint ?

Comment: Yeah why not. There are gazillion ways. For eg: use spring security on top of it.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Can you please provide me some reference/pointers?

Comment: Are you familar with Spring Security?

Comment: remove the @RequestMapping

Comment: @HoWaiChan I think the concern is that the application is jar.

Comment: If there is same jar then it is not possible even familar with Spring Security